# How to change the model column value while returning json data using django-rest framewrok

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a modal that stores an integer number, user will be giving hexadecimal number and I am converting into integer and storing it in database, Now I need to expose my model through rest-api...by doing this user would be seeing integer value not hexadecimal, how can convert integer back to hexadecimal and show it to the user in rest-api?

Model:

```
class Address:
    base_addr = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

serializer:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = (base_addr,
```

)

viewset:

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = Address
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
    filter_fields = ('base_addr')
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `serializers.SerializerMethodField`

```
class Address:
    base_addr = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    def get_hexadecimal(self):
        // your convertion logic here
        return addr_in_hexadecimal
```

then

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    bae_addr_hex = serializers.Field(source='get_hexadecimal')
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('bae_addr_hex', ...)
```

Comment: How about you can't change your model? you just need to add a method

Comment: Thanks trinchet, One more small information if the user queries from rest-api like..  ?address = "0x5656576" How do I convert it back to interger and search in model. (Iam new to rest)

Comment: Before answer that, why you need to store Integers intead of the hexadecinal numbers? it seems you are overloading logic just for this

Comment: anyway you can see how filter/search here http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering.html#filtering-against-the-url, an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186065/1904584, hope that helps :)