# Negation or exclude filter in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I've used Django REST Framework for quite a while now, but have come across a situation where I need to retrieve everything but a known relation in an API view. After looking through the documentation again, I cannot see any built-in mechanism to achieve this. I realize I can override `get_queryset()` in my ListView and parse custom URL query parameters and then do the filtering, but I'm curious if anyone else has a more elegant solution?

**Update**

After a little more research, this seems to be more of a django-filter question, and I cannot find mention of any exclude functionality. I did find this:

https://bitbucket.org/mjs7231/django-rest-framework-filtering

which does provide excluding values from the results.

Comment: Can you revise the accepted answer? I think my answer points to an easier solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are searching for [custom filter backend](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#custom-generic-filtering)

Comment: Thanks, this is preferable to a one off `get_queryset` override. I don't see any other way. I guess this is more an issue with django-filter not having this functionality.

Comment: Overriding get_queryset can be messy if filters are complex and multiple. Alternate way here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258338/django-rest-framework-filtering/35506369#35506369

Answer (score 11):

Use the `exclude` parameter in filter's definition inside your filterset.

```
class MyFilterSet(FilterSet):
    negated_field__not = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='negated_field', exclude=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['some_field', 'some_other_field']

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyFilterSet
```

That's equivalent to `Model.objects.all().exclude(negated_field__exact=value)`. Then, from your frontend you can exclude requesting an url like this: `/api/my_viewset/?negated_field__not=value`.

Comment: Thanks it works, but in my case i need to change `NumberFilter` `name` attribute to `field_name`

Comment: yup this work. just need to add the ?status__not=15 something like this then will exclude status that is 15

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#automatic-filter-negationexclusion). This package supports exclusion syntax in query string **key!=value**.

For example, /api/search?**name!=Alex**

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. Link-dominated answers can become invalid

Comment: Does this work for __in style statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a conditional on queryset as this:

```
# Default queryset
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

# FILTERING
# Get all query parameters from the request
query_params = request.query_params

# Iterate over all parameters and apply filters
for param, value in query_params.items():
   try:
       if "!" not in value:
           queryset_tmp = queryset.filter(**{param: value})
       else:
           value_to_exclude = value.split('!')[1]
           queryset_tmp = queryset.exclude(**{param: value_to_exclude})
   except:
       queryset_tmp = queryset
   queryset = queryset_tmp
```

This way, all you have to do is send a "!" before the value you want to exclude. E.g.: /this/example/filter?**status=!done**