# Using custom methods in filter with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I would like to filter against query params in my REST API - [see django docs on this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-query-parameters).
However, one parameter I wish to filter by is only available via a model @property

example models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, related_name='listing')
    ...
    @property
    def category(self):
        return self.product.assets[0].category.name
```

Here is the setup for my Listing API in accordance with [django-filter docs](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)

```
    class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        product = django_filters.CharFilter(name='product__name')
        category = django_filters.CharFilter(name='category') #DOES NOT WORK!!

        class Meta:
            model = Listing
            fields = ['product','category']

    class ListingList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Listing.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ListingSerializer
        filter_class = ListingFilter
```

How can I appropriately filter by listing.category? It is not available on the listing model directly.

Comment: For such cases, this answer of another question might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258338/django-rest-framework-filtering/35506369#35506369

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the 'action' parameter to specify a custom method - [see django-filter docs](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#action)

First define a method that filters a queryset using the value of the category parameter:

```
    def filter_category(queryset, value):
        if not value:
            return queryset

        queryset = ...custom filtering on queryset using 'value'...
        return queryset
```

Listing filter should look like this:

```
    class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        ...
        category = django_filters.CharFilter(action=filter_category)
        ...
```

Comment: Just a quick note that the django-filter `action` has been replaced by `method`. http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html

Comment: [Doc Reference MIgration 1.0 Changed `action` to `method`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migration.html?highlight=MethodFilter#methodfilter-and-filter-action-replaced-by-filter-method-382)

Answer (score -2):

For sake of database speed, you should just add the category to your listing model

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, related_name='listing')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Then use a [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) to keep the field updated

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def updateCategory(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    product = instance
    product.listing.category = product.assets[0].category.name
    product.listing.save()
```

Then filter by it's name as you would any other field:

```
class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    category = django_filters.CharFilter(name='category__name')
    ...
```