# Use Custom Filter with Django ModelChoice Filter

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I am trying to create use the filter method with django-filters

See an example of the models below:

```
class Chicken(TimeStampedModel):
    eggs = ForeignKey(Egg)

class Egg(TimeStampedModel):
    hatched = BooleanField(default=False)
```

See an example of my current set up for the filter:

```
class ChickenFilter(FilterSet):
    eggs__contains = ModelChoiceFilter(name="eggs", method='hatched_eggs', queryset=Eggs.objects.all())

   def hatched_eggs(self, queryset, name, value):
      print "We got eggs"
     return queryset.filter(eggs__hatched=True)
```

The problem is that the method doesnt even print We got eggs when I hit the url. It just returns an empty queryset.

Comment: What is the querystring that you're using? If `eggs__contains` isn't in the querystring, the filter won't execute.

Comment: I am going through similar issue. Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 8):

I did it like below:

In my urls I sent `?ids=1,2,3,4`

```
class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    ids = django_filters.CharFilter(method='ids__in')

    def ids__in(self, queryset, value, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if args:
                ids = args[0].split(',')
                ids = [int(_id) for _id in ids]
                queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=ids)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return queryset
```

Comment: That's help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was going through the same problem. My `method` was not being called.

So came to conclusion, I can make a workaround using:

[Using custom methods in filter with django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414926/using-custom-methods-in-filter-with-django-rest-framework)

```
class ChickenFilter(FilterSet):
    eggs__contains = CharFilter(action='hatched_eggs')

def hatched_eggs(queryset, value):
      print "We got eggs"
     if value:
         return queryset.filter(eggs__hatched=True)
     return queryset
```

Comment: action didnt work for me, i've used method instead.